# Angular 2 Service Injection outside of Components, Services, etc

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Imagine a service like a `LoggingService`, which has a `log(msg: string)` method. With Angular 2 Dependency Injection it is easy to have an instance of the service in a component. However, I could not find a solid solution to have the LoggingService in any plain class which is not an Angular 2 component, service, etc.

E.g. the application has a file blacklist.ts which contains:

```
export class Blacklist {
    isBlacklisted(name: string): boolean {
        let result = false;

        if(value == "Alice" || value == "Bob") {
            result = true;
            LoggingService.log("Name'" + name + "' is blacklisted");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Assume the `LoggingService` is provided in the `AppModule`. How can I retrieve an instance of the service in the above example?

Comment: And why don't you make Blacklist a service?

Comment: You can get a hold of the (root) dependency injector programmatically and then search its providers registry for a specific service, but it doesn't sense in your example. If you're in plain class and you're outside Angular context, you'll have a hard time communicating with Angular entities. Like JB said, what's wrong with turning your code into a service?

Answer (score 1):

I will use [TypeScript decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) for that purpose now:

```
export class Blacklist {

    @logger
    logger: LoggingService;
    
    isBlacklisted(name: string): boolean {
        let result = false;

        if(value == "Alice" || value == "Bob") {
            result = true;
            this.logger.log("Name'" + name + "' is blacklisted");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Edit: The decorator code:

```
export const logger = (context?: Function) => {
  return (target: Object, key: string | symbol) => {
      target[key] = new Logger(null, (context ? context.name : target.constructor.name));
  }
}
```

Comment: Would've been nice if you shared the decorator code aswell

Comment: do i understand correctly that you create a new Logger Service object for this purpose? I found this question when trying to figure out how to access an angular service, but since i have values stored in the service i would not want to create a new one

Comment: @JeremiasNater Yes, the decorator code from my edit creates a new instance of Logger and passes either the context.name or the target.constructor.name to the constructor of the Logger. However, I think you can rewrite the decorator code to return always the same object

Answer (score 0):

Either LoggingService be a static class
So that you could use it without the instance 
Or you need and instance of it to invoke the methods

> the whole purpose is to support re-usability
>   **use it like this**

```
import {LoggingService} from 'path/to/service'
export class Blacklist {
    private loggingService:LoggingService;
    isBlacklisted(name: string): boolean {
        let result = false;

        if(value == "Alice" || value == "Bob") {
            result = true;
            this.loggingService.log("Name'" + name + "' is blacklisted");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: so when using "private loggingService:LoggingService;" you retrieve the angular instance of the service? These declarations always seemed confusing to me becuase they look just like a typing without an assigned value.

Comment: Now that i've read more about the Dependency injections system i am pretty certain that your answer will not inject the LoggingService, but have undefined as value of property loggingService

Answer (score -3):

Import it in the component

```
import {LoggingService} from 'path/to/service';
```

Put it in the constructor:

```
constructor(private logSvc: LoggingService){}
```

Comment: Title says "outside of components, services..."